# How to find out what parts of the physical memory contain data/instructions of what processes?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, kernel, process

I would like to know, where the code and the data of the currently running processes are being placed physically in RAM. It should be very informative if it is possible to represent this distribution graphically, so that the distinctive process IDs are the points with distinctive colors. How and where to get this information? It looks like /proc doesn't provide it. Should I write a kernel module or a conventional user space application can also retrieve such info (if yes - how?) ?

Comment: Why do you care about *physical* memory, not *virtual* memory? The kernel is free to move pages inside the physical memory, (e.g. when swapping-out then swapping-in some pages). I believe you cannot reliably get that information easily... and I nearly guess your question is wrongly formulated... (because process consume virtual memory, not physical RAM, so it does not make sense to speak of the physical RAM consumed by some given process...).

Comment: No, I formulated it properly. It is because my RAM has non-uniformly distributed access times.

Comment: One possible solution would be to use `numactl` to specify on which numa node you want to allocate your memory. You can also use libnuma to do this in a programatic way. Check man numactl

Answer (score 3):

I 100% agree with the "why would you?" comments.

But if you do want it, a kernel module could do it.
Given a virtual address in the current address space (if you run in a system call done from a process, the current process), you can translate it to the physical address.
Using the macros `pgd_offset_k`, `pud_offset`, `pmd_offset`, `pte_offset` in sequence, you should be able to get the physical address.

@Daniel's answer would help you know what addresses you want.

You can also try to use `mem_map[i].address_space`. It should contain some ownership information per physical page. I don't really know how to make sense of it.

Note that there may be overlap between processes. Libraries such as libc, which are loaded by multiple processes, may have a single copy in physical memory.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of information is provided by the `maps` file. It represents the memory mappings of all the modules that the process has loaded into memory.

This is the information for my `init`, have a look :

```
00400000-00408000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 261498                             /sbin/init
00607000-00608000 r--p 00007000 08:02 261498                             /sbin/init
00608000-00609000 rw-p 00008000 08:02 261498                             /sbin/init
01336000-01357000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fa740f1c000-7fa7410b2000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 265802                     /lib/libc-2.15.so
7fa7410b2000-7fa7412b2000 ---p 00196000 08:02 265802                     /lib/libc-2.15.so
7fa7412b2000-7fa7412b6000 r--p 00196000 08:02 265802                     /lib/libc-2.15.so
7fa7412b6000-7fa7412b8000 rw-p 0019a000 08:02 265802                     /lib/libc-2.15.so
7fa7412b8000-7fa7412bc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fa7412bc000-7fa7412dd000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 265813                     /lib/ld-2.15.so
7fa7414ce000-7fa7414d1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fa7414db000-7fa7414dc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fa7414dc000-7fa7414dd000 r--p 00020000 08:02 265813                     /lib/ld-2.15.so
7fa7414dd000-7fa7414de000 rw-p 00021000 08:02 265813                     /lib/ld-2.15.so
7fa7414de000-7fa7414df000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fffeb8c5000-7fffeb8e6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fffeb9ff000-7fffeba00000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

The "r--p" are the flags of each associated region. The "x" means that the given region contains executable data, i.e. instructions. In this case, we have the region `00400000-00408000` marked as read-only, executable and private, and mapped into `/sbin/init`. Therefore, this is the location that stores the .text section of the executable.

Comment: No, the `/proc/$$/maps` and  `/proc/$$/smaps` (.e.g. `/proc/self/maps`) represent the *virtual memory map*. Apparently, the original poster cares about *physical* memory (which I think is useless) ...

Comment: I found that the content of maps for many processes is empty.

Answer (score 0):

you can rely on the physical addresses only if you lock them into memory else physical address information is pointless as they changes frequently. A user space application can't provide physical address information as it need to read page table entries. you certainly need to write  kernel module for it and can use information provided by @Daniel and @ugoren. you can get more info [here](http://kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand006.html)